# C++, accessing std::map element via const reference

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

I have a proble with const. say I have :

```
class A{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const A& myObj);

   private:
    std::map<int,int> someMap;
    int someInteger;
 };
 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,const A& myObj){
  os<<myObj.someInteger<<std::endl;
  os<<myObj.someMap[0]<<std::endl;
  }
```

This kind of code generates an error at compilation due to a const conflict with the map (if I comment the line printing the map value all is fine), and if I get rid of the 'const' in the function prototype all is fine. I really do not see where is the problem..

Any help please?

Comment: I think you meant `myObj.someMap[0]`.

Comment: `os<<myObj<<someMap[0]` should be `os<<myObj.someMap[0]` to flesh out what chris stated.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) is not const, because it inserts an element if one does not already exist. In c++11, you can use [`std::map::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) instead:

```
myObj.someMap.at(0)
```

Otherwise, you can check whether the element exists first using [`std::map::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find),

```
if (myObj.find(0) != myObj.end())
{
  // element with key 0 exists in map
} else 
{
  // do something else.
}
```

Comment: Note that std::map::at() is built into gcc from 2003 and on.

Comment: THANKS A LOT. I understand the problem. And the operator at works well with my g++!!